# How to find type value while reading from text file?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a text file and I need to find type of text files reading line.For example I have a text file like this:

```
1
test
3.123123
13/21/13
```

how can i do distinguish this types.I need to write console String, integer, date or float in Java

Comment: how was that text file created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use regular expressions. For instance, if it's all digits (or a minus/plus sign followed by digits), it's an int. Have a regex for each of the types and try them one after another. If it's not an int, see if it's a float; if it's not a float, see if it's a date; and so on. if all checks fail, it's a string.

You could *also* try the brute force approach of attempting to randomly parse stuff and looking at what doesn't throw an exception, but that's not a good idea.

Comment: I have done this with pregmatch its not hard to making this thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic solution. You have to parse and analyse your input line-by-line.

To distinguish Integer you can use

`Integer.parseInt(s)` and unless ParsingException is thrown assume that the data is Integer. The same is about Double. Date is probably a problem because date can appear in different formats.

I think that in your case to simplify you code it is better to use patterns:

```
Pattern[] patterns = Pattern[] {Pattern.compile("^\\d+$"), Pattern.compile("^\\d+\\.\\d*$"), Pattern.compile("^\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}$")};
Class<?> types = new Class[] {Integer.class, Double.class, Date.class};
for (int i - 0;  i < patterns.length;  i++) {
    if (patterns[i].matches(str)) {
        return types[i];
    }
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible to do perfectly. For example, `3.123123` in the question can be a String, a float or a double.

You may want to convert everything that looks like a double to a double, everything else which looks like a long to a long, everything else which looks like a boolean to a boolean, everything else which looks like a date to a date, and everything else to a string. To do that, I'd use BufferedReader.readLine or Scanner.next (to split on spaces, tabs etc. as well as newlines) to read the next thing, and then static methods like Long.parseLong in a try...catch block to detect parse errors (i.e. when it doesn't look like a long). Example:

```
String thing = bufferedReader.readLine();
long longValue;
boolean looksLikeALong = false;
try {
  longValue = Long.parseLong(thing);
  looksLikeALong = true;
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see what you've tried so far, or what doesn't work, or what your thinking process has been.

There are a few ways to solve this without thinking very hard about it; a few of which are using a regex, using instanceof or using some of the parsing methods parseInt, parseLong etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a perfect solution, you need to write a parser that takes the grammar that defines all the data types that may appear in the text file. Even regular expression matching will help if you dont want to match complex data types.